# Start Facebook session on iPhone, resume in PHP

Tags: php, ios, facebook

A user logs into a Facebook session in my iPhone app, and then I call a PHP page on my server that needs to use that session to access the user's Facebook account. Is it possible to start the session in the PHP page and be authenticated automatically? Perhaps by passing in the session key and secret from the iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

If you get user credentials in your iPhone app you can then pass them to PHP using simple POST or GET request. Note however that if your connection to PHP service is not SSLed this could become a huge security issue.

Comment: Thanks, my connection is using SSL. Do the credentials you speak of consist of just the session key and session secret? Or is there more?

Comment: I'm not familiar with FB API but you'd probably need user's login and password.